# PostgreSQL JDBC - can drop but not recreate indexes

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, foreign-keys, indexing

I've been searching for an answer, but no luck so far...

I want to perform bulk operations on a database with potentially millions of records, reading the PostgreSQL guide: '13.4 Populating a Database' [1](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/populate.html), it suggests removing indexes and foreign-key constraints to speed up the copy operation.

I'm trying to accomplish this using JDBC statements, I'm finding that I can drop the indexes without any issue, but recreating them after populating the database has problems. I get a syntax error 'at or near' the name of the index that I am creating:

```
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
String query = "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX type_uk ON cell (field1, field2, field3, field4) WHERE field3 AND field4 IS NOT NULL TABLESPACE lcindex";

stmt.executeUpdate(query);
connection.commit();
```

If I execute this query in psql, it successfully creates the index though, so I'm a bit confused...

Any help, insights, suggestions, etc. would be much appreciated :)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am able to create such indexes (without TABLESPACE) using JDBC from Jython. Give us more info about: is it possible to create simple indexes? What version of JDBC and PostgreSQL do you use?

Comment: I've only been trying to drop & re-create these unique indexes, I'll try dropping a simple index and get back to you...

I'm using JDBC 8.4-701 with PostgreSQL 8.3.3.

Comment: does the postgresql server log show the error as well, with the same SQL that you are sending? (just in case something is happening to the SQL on the way somehow...)

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment on the answer like Michal Niklas did, but your sql statement is illegal in postgres and cannot work. My guess:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX type_uk ON cell (field1, field2, field3, field4) TABLESPACE lcindex 
  where field3 is not null and field4 is not null;
```

- tablespace should come before where
- every field in there where clause has
  to have "is not null"

Comment: Ok, I'll try that out ASAP and get back to you guys so that others will know if this worked or not. Thanks very much :)